# Why do I have an infinite While loop?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a basic loop and I don't understand why it prints an infinite loop instead of -1 through -24.

```
net_distance = 0

def go_back(distance_backwards1):
    while net_distance != net_distance - distance_backwards1:
        net_distance = net_distance - 1
        print(net_distance)

go_back(24)
```

Comment: do you know what scope is?

Comment: because 24 != 0

Comment: Looks like you are subtracting the wrong variable. I think you want to subtract `distance_backwards1` and also print the same variable.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Most of all, please explain *exactly* what you don't understand from the output you get when you trace this code. Include that trace in your MRE.

Answer (score 2):

The condition in your `while` loop

```
net_distance != net_distance - distance_backwards1
```

is — after subtracting the common term `net_distance` from both sides — the same as

```
0 != -distance_backwards1:
```

i.e. the same as

```
0 != distance_backwards1:
```

It means that if the parameter `distance_backwards1` of your function `go_back()` is not zero, the condition will be still `True` and — consequently — your `while` loop will be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are decreasing the wrong variable. Also you need to print before you decrease. Your while loop is decreasing `net_distance` and it keeps going into negative value and will NEVER reach the value you passed. Instead you need to decrease the value you sent so it reaches `net_distance`

Minor tweaks to your code and it prints backwards.

```
net_distance = 0 #looks like you want to get here

def go_back(distance_backwards1):

    while net_distance != distance_backwards1: #check if you got to 0
        print(distance_backwards1) #print the number first
        distance_backwards1 = distance_backwards1 - 1 #decrement by 1

go_back(24)
```

The output will be:

```
24
23
22
21
20
19
18
17
16
15
14
13
12
11
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably wanted

```
def go_back(distance_backwards1):
    while distance_backwards1 > 1:
        distance_backwards1 = distance_backwards1 - 1
        print(-distance_backwards1)

go_back(24)
```

Not that you don't need you variable `net_distance`.

You simply decrease your parameter and print its opposite (i.e. its "minus" value) in your loop, controlled only by the condition `net_distance > 1` .